# React - How to set a new nested object property using just one line?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, setstate

I'm using a state to store a object with this structure:

```
    {
            "fullName": "John",
            "birthdate": "2000-02-27",
            "cpfNumber": "11408247910",
            "telephoneNumber": "47996034002",
            "emailAddress": "john@gmail.com",
            "address": {
                "mainAddress": "Rua Amoroso Costa",
                "numberAddress": "171",
                "neighborHood": "Jardim das Américas",
                "complementInfo": "Casa",
                "zipCode": "81530-150"
            }
      }
```

I'm using a form to fill this data using the onChange function:

```
<input type="email" 
   name="emailAddress" 
   id="emailAddress" 
   onChange={(e) => setFormPatient({ ...formPatient, ["emailAddress"]: e.target.value })} />
```

I have been trying some different approaches to update the data from the `address` nested object but I'm not getting there. One of my failed intents was:

```
onChange={(e) => setFormPatient({ ...formPatient, address: "mainAddress": e.target.value })
```

**My question is the following: is there a way to make this one liner work for a nested object like `address`?**

Comment: I think you’re just missing some curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the object in question is
not an array, try to use it like this and check if it works:

```
 <input type="mainAddress" 
  name="mainAddress" 
  id="mainAddress" 
  onChange={(e) => setFormPatient({ ...formPatient, address: { 
     ...formPatient.address,
     mainAddress: e.target.value 
   }
 })} />
```

Edit: Fixed based on Chris Heald feedback, ty!

Comment: You'll need to splat out `formPatient.address` inside of the new `address`, otherwise the splatted address is replaced by the given address, not merged with it.